# Is it possible to create a JSON using ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I'm developing an E-commerce App similar to Amazon, I have a requirement to create an JSON with Array of Dictionaries.
Eg:

```
    {
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id":1,
            "quantity":2
        },
        {
            "product_id":2,
            "quantity":2
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible with ObjectMapper framework? The products are generated dynamically, not a fixed number of products. Each time we check out, products list are different based on user selection.

Comment: For Swift 4 use the `Codable` protocol and `JSONEncoder()`. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly.. yes it does. It says so on the project [homepage](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper):

You can do it this way:

```
let JSONString = user.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true)
```

or

```
let JSONString = Mapper().toJSONString(user, prettyPrint: true)
```

For Swift 4, use the `Codable` protocol and `JSONEncoder()`. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)